# Max Players Formula

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

When I first started running a Bukkit server there was this formula I used using my system info that determined how many players I should set max players to.

I have a new computer, and I forget the formula, and I've tried to Google it, but there is no info!

Can someone tell me the formula please?

Comment: The server load depends *very* much on the plugins you have, so I'd doubt any formula that tries to predict that. It might be good idea to gradually increase the max players until you notice the performance starts to suffer. If you really want some guidelines, you can look at the tables at: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server/Requirements/Dedicated

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [this website](http://canihostaminecraftserver.com/).

BUT, as Kcats said, the server performance depends *a lot* on your plugins, so just reduce the number when your server can't take it anymore.